# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, developer

I'm trying to display some dependent field once case details page is loading but based on logic which i written that is working for admin only
If i login with community portal user case details page is missing and getting an error.Any help ?

> error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'value')

```
<template>

    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Case"
    onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit} onload={handleOnLoad} data-id="caseForm">   <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-4">
                    <lightning-input-field disabled={isDisabledOrEnabledAllFields} required field-name="ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c" data-fieldname
="ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c" value={caseObj.ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c} onchange={handleFieldChange}></lightning-input-field><br>
                 
                    <template if:true={showFreq}>
                        <lightning-input-field disabled={isDisabledOrEnabledAllFields} required
                                               field-name="ET_Frequency_Period__c" 
                                               data-fieldname ="ET_Frequency_Period__c"
                                               value={caseObj.ET_Frequency_Period__c} 
                                               onchange={handleFieldChange}>
                        </lightning-input-field> 
                    </template>
                </div>  </lightning-record-edit-form>   
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement,api, track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue }  from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import changeOwnerCase from '@salesforce/apex/CaseCreationsController.changeOwnerCase';
import OWNER_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Case.OwnerId';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import UserNameFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';
export default class Et_EMEAChangeInInterestPeriod extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

@track showFreq = false;

    handleOnLoad(event){
        var record = event.detail.records;
        var reqType = record[this.recordId].fields.Status.value;
        this.name = record[this.recordId].fields.Status.value;

        if(reqType === 'Unsubmitted'){
            this.isEditable = false;
        }else if(reqType === 'Assigned'){
            this.isDisabledOrEnabledAllFields = true;
        }else if(reqType === 'Waiting on Submitter'){
            this.isDisabledOrEnabledAllFields = false;
        }else{
            this.isDisabledOrEnabledAllFields = true;
        }
        if(reqType === 'Unsubmitted' || reqType === 'Waiting on Submitter'){
            this.isDisabledButton = false;
        }
        
The below logic is working for system admin but for portal user login case details page is missing. getting an error - 
lwr_app:1 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
        
        var reqType1 = record[this.recordId].fields.ET_Frequency_of_interest_period__c.value;
        console.log('reqType1----->'+reqType1);
        if(reqType1 === 'other - please specify'){

           this.showFreq = true;
       }else{
           this.showFreq = false;
       }
            
    }
```

Comment: Check the record and field access in the profile/permission sets you are using for the portal login.